# android Json parser offline

Tags: android, json

I'm new to the android world and i have some problem.
I'm developing a project under android and it require a json parser. I get my json file from a web service developed under Zend framework, the link to the web service : "manganew:8080/wsmanganew/manga/manga/idmanga/1" and the content of the json file is

```
{
"manga": [
            {
                "idmanga":"1",
                "titre":"naruto",
                "episode":"145",
                "url":"http:\/\/naruto.com\/",
                "image":null,
                "description":"Naruto Shippuuden .",
                "tv":"TV Tokyo",
                "dtdebut":"2013-05-23 12:30:00",
                "iduser":"1"
            }
        ]}
```

I'm following this tutorial "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/".

i don't know how index to the web service link in the android, any help will be useful.

thank you

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it: your title tells 'android Json parser offline', while your question tells about a remote json. Can you clarify a little please?

Comment: i downloaded the tutorial project, but i can't load the file and i don't know why because I'm new at android.

Comment: Have you thought about using spring for android? It would hide the complexity of the task and you could do this in about three lines of code. If that would be ok for you I could provide you an example

Answer (score 0):

so, what do you need to do? download json object from that url into your app?
that code has method getJSONFromUrl in it's class, you should use it
though, according to comments it has flaws in it.

to read string from file use this code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/docs/file.json"));
String line, results = "";
while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    results += line;

reader.close();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(results);
```

replace path with path to your file

Comment: i did download the project, and i changed what i need to change, but it didn't work, i don't know how to index to a local address

Comment: have you tried this? `jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://manganew:8080/wsmanganew/manga/manga/idmanga/1");`

Comment: the prolem is that the json file is in my computer a local file

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\file.json"));
String line, results = "";
while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    results += line;

reader.close();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(results);
```

Replace with your local machine download field path `C:\\file.json`